# Sending special characters in XMPP

Tags: xmpp

So I'm trying to send a string like this

```
<message to="me"><body>\<foobar\></body></message>
```

The brackets seem to stop the transmission of the message, is there any way to escape the characters for example?  How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to properly escape the content for XML. In your case, the message must end up like this:

```
<message to="me"><body>\&lt;foobar\&gt;</body></message>
```

For an entity escaper, have a look into [StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.1/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html) (I assume that you're doing this in Java).

Answer (score 2):

As XMPP is an XML application, I'd try replacing `<` with `&lt;`, `&` with `&amp;` and, probably not necessarily, `>` with `&gt;`.